# Robotics Projects

Tags: project

I think it would be really cool to learn how to move a physical 3D object with a program. I know how to draw or import a 2D object, for example, and have it grow/move in a bunch of different ways. Of course a real object can't be grown with a program, but can it be moved?

My understanding is that a lot of commercial mechanical products (factory 'arms', robot vacuum's, etc) have chips in them that execute commands. Is there a way to do this without having the hardware knowledge to create a chip? By somehow attaching an object to a computer and running a program?

If there is a similar way, do you have a create your object with a certain type of material (metal?), or execute these commands with a certain programming language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You certainly don't need to be an expert in chip design to make something move.  There are tons of projects on the web that show you how to make things move using servos or DC motors, controlled with the appropriate electronics.  Have you heard of microcontrollers?

Here is an example project you could do to make something move:
http://www.pololu.com/docs/0J42

An easier starting point would be the Arduino Inventor's Kit:
http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1644

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions! I will definitely look into them. I am not familiar with DC motors or servos [total noob in this area, as my initial post implies], so I think starting out with a kit is a good idea.

Comment: My original idea was to do a sort of bio-robotics project for class, since we've been learning about the boid (flocking) algorithm, the golem project @ Brandeis, and evolving creatures using genetic algorithms. I thought it would be a cool final project to do something mechanical that involves programming, instead of just simulating it on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple program in shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while : ; do
   eject -T 
   sleep 1
   eject -T
   sleep 1
done
```

If supported, this will open/close the CDROM tray once a second. Now you can make an automatic [food dispenser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIMNCdjb9Qw) for your cat.

[image]
<sub>(source: [123rf.com](http://us.cdn1.123rf.com/168nwm/violin/violin0701/violin070100058/726755-dvd-cd-disc-in-open-drive-isolated-on-white.jpg))</sub>

Comment: That's actually pretty cool; I'll try that. But I was trying to figure out how to move something that isn't physically part of a computer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [Lego Mindstorm Robotics Kits](http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/Default.aspx). These are pretty cool, and package up all the stuff (hardware and software) you need for experimenting. Depending on where you're at in your schooling, some high-schools have robotics teams that use these kits.

**edit** this now points to the robotics research area on area51.

As part of the stackexchange.com world, check out [area51 robotics Research](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29987/robotics-research)

**edit** sorry, read your profile, CS at IU cool!

Or if you want to get serious and have the time and money, check out a local-junior college for electronics classes. To get any good at this, you'll need to know how to write programs AND use a soldering iron, work with resistors, capacitors, transistors, IC chips, etc, etc.

Finally, one time I ran into an experimenters website, but I've lost the link. Certainly if you google for specific stuff using experimenter as part of your query, you'll find a lot of good stuff.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that stackexchange link. I've definitely heard of lego mindstorms but they are a little pricy. Also, I would want more of a programming challenge rather than a drag-n-drop language, although I've heard of some pretty cool creations (ie the rubix cube solver). I'll probably just pick up an intro robotics book and learn the basics that way. Just thought more SO people would be interested in robotics, since (from an outside perspective) it's the coolest part of CS

Answer (score 0):

I really enjoyed doing some Arduino based projects.  You can buy the Arduino board or even build your own with some bread board, there are tutorials for it if you want to learn.  You can also buy cheap knockoffs that are a few dollars and work just as well.

I built a robotic fish out of 3 servos and an adruino board.  It is somewhat similar to this one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUIy6XApZos

I used the basic swimming algorithm and adapted it to my own purposes:

```
void loop()
{
for (i=0; i<360; i++) {

pos1 = i+2*phase;
pos2 = i+phase;
pos3 = i;

if (pos1>359) pos1-=360;
if (pos2>359) pos2-=360;
if (pos3>359) pos3-=360;

if (pos1>179) pos1=360-pos1; 
if (pos2>179) pos2=360-pos2;
if (pos3>179) pos3=360-pos3; 


Servo1.write(pos1R); 
Servo2.write(pos2R); 
Servo3.write(pos3R); 
delay(time);
```

Very easy to do, the programming language simplified to a degree as well.